# Sorting posts by ACF field

Tags: meta-query

I am trying to sort posts by the 'prempost' ACF field, but it's not working (just shows default order). Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? ACF support suggested that I use http_build_query, which I've done below, but still no cigar:/

```
<?php 
  $meta_query = array(
  'relation' => 'OR',
  array(
    'key' => 'prempost',
    'compare' => 'IN'
  ),
array(
    'key' => 'prempost',
    'compare' => 'NOT IN'
  )
);

$args = array(
'meta_query' => $meta_query,
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'meta_key' => 'prempost',
'order' => 'ASC',
);?>

<?php $new_args = http_build_query($args); ?>
<?php $posts = query_posts($query_string.'&'.$new_args); ?>

//begin loop
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: I don't understand your logic here. You're querying posts that has the specific key or that don't have the specific key. This just translates to getting all posts regardless

Comment: It must get all the posts, but it must order them with the "prempost" posts first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going to this in one query, you will need to do two queries. The first query will hold the posts which will hold the meta key, the second will be the posts without the meta key.

(*Just a note: **never** use `query_posts` unless you intentionally wants to break things*)

You can try something like this

```
$args1 = array(
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'prempost',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$query1 = new WP_Query($args1);

//Do your stuff here

$args2 = array(
    'meta_key' => 'prempost',
    'compare' => 'NOT IN'
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$query2 = new WP_Query($args2);

//Do your stuff here
```

You can also maybe try to get all the posts at once and then sorting them with php using `usort()`

Comment: Hi there Pieter, thanks for your answer. I'm a bit stumped though. I am displaying posts based on two dropdowns (taxonomy and custom post type search). Would it still be advisable to use WP_Query, or can I only use query_posts in this case?

Comment: Could I do something like this? `$query = new WP_Query($query_string.'&'.$args);` It seems to be working, but would that be the _right_ way to go about it?

Comment: That would be fine. Just don't use `query_posts`, it break the main query and some functionalities plugins and some features in your theme needs

Comment: I think I'm getting somewhere slowly:) I tried using usort, but had no luck with that so trying your first suggestion. My second wp_query looks like this: `$query2 = new WP_Query($query_string.'&meta_key=prempost&compare=NOT IN&order=ASC');`. It's not working, and I suspect it's because of the space in "NOT IN". Do you have any idea how I could work around that?

Comment: I figured it out. I put the args into a proper array format, and found that I had previous 'test' fields of prempost that were causing it to not work correctly. Oh my glory. Anyways, thanks so much for your help! :)

Comment: My pleasure. Glad you were able to resolve this. Enjoy :-)